# My Facebook Like Button Not Opening Up Facebook App

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I am creating a facebook like button on my app and would like to redirect them to the actual app first. Although, it keeps opening up in Safari. I am testing on my phone & I have facebook

I've tried

```
fb://profile/<id>
fb://page/<id>
fb://<id>
```

And still every request redirects to Safari.

I have my deployment target on 9.0.

```
   let appUrl : URL = URL(string: "fb://profile/{myId}")!
        let webUrl : URL = URL(string: "https://www.facebook.com/{myFacebookUsername}")!

        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(appUrl) {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(appUrl)
            print("in app")
        } else {

            UIApplication.shared.openURL(webUrl)
            print("webbb")
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your `Info.plist` file to support a launch of facebook if you haven't done that already. 
Just open the file as source code and enter this:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>fb</string>
</array>
```